# pass by reference or by value in variable assignment of struct, Golang

Tags: go, reference, variable-assignment, pass-by-value

```
type temp struct{
   val int
}

variable1 := temp{val:5}  // 1
variable2 := &temp{val:6} // 2
```

In 2, the reference is stored in the `variable2`.

In 1, does the copy operation is taking place? Or `variable1` is also pointed to the same memory portion? or does have a different memory portion than `temp{val:5}` have?

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go for such basic language fundamentals. There are no references in Go, a pointer is a value. 1 makes a copy.

Answer (score 3):

`temp{val:5}` is a [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals), it creates a value of type `temp`.

In the first example you used a [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), which is equivalent to

```
var variable1 = temp{val: 5}
```

There is a single variable created here (`variable1`) which is initialized with the value `temp{val: 5}`.

In the second example you take the address of a composite literal. That does create a variable, initialized with the literal's value, and the address of this variable will be the result of the expression. This pointer value will be assigned to the variable `variable2`.

[Spec: Compositle literals:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

> [Taking the address](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators) of a composite literal generates a pointer to a unique [variable](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Variables) initialized with the literal's value.